# Nested Functions, Closures and Scope

Tags: javascript, nested, closures, lexical-scope, lexical-closures

I've been trying to wrap my head around scope, specially closures.
I know that there are many posts about the topic, and I've been reading a lot. But most places refer to the topic as advanced, and use terminology that is relatively difficult to grasp. I would like to be absolutely sure that I've got the basics right, so that I don't go venture into the more intricate topics with a wrong idea of how functions really work.

So... I picked a basic function, and would really like for someone to tell me if what I think its happening *under the hood* is what is actually happening.

This is the code:

```
function sum(a) {


  return function(b) {  
    return a+b
  }
}

console.log( sum(1)(sum(2)))
```

(I know that it's not actually do the sum, I was tweaked with it, to try to understand what was going on in each step.)

So, my main doubt was why A was 1, and not 2. I reached the conclusion that the closure is created, as soon as `function(b)`is created to take `sum(2)` as an argument, right after being returned by `sum(1)`. Therefore, by the definition of closure, I'm assuming that at the time the function is created it also saves the lexical environment (in which `a = 1`). Is this right?

I've made a diagram of the steps.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I understand the code, but not your diagram, so not being clear what you mean by the capital `A`s I'm not sure how to answer. Note that `sum(2)` returns a new function that you never call, so its closure is irrelevant here. Also, given that `sum(2)` returns a new function, why would you pass that as an argument to the return from `sum(1)`? It doesn't make sense to add the number 1 to a function reference. JS will do it (resulting in a string), but it seems a rather strange test case.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's supposed to `a = 1`, and each rectangle represents a lexical environment. Ok, I think what you just said about the return of `sum(2)` never being called, helps to make sense of it. Just to clarify, there are still two closures occurring here right? One when `sum(1)` is first defined and the other for `sum(2)`

Comment: @Sean You got several responses but didn't accept any. What exactly  cause you problems yet?

Answer (score -1):

> Whatever facility we use to transport an inner function outside of its lexical scope, it will maintain a scope reference to where it was originally declared, and wherever we execute it, that closure will be exercised.

In the next function you will see how the `greet` will use a variable `salute` declared inside the `greeting` function even when this is no longer being called, this is called a Closure.

```
function greeting(name) {
  var salute = "Hello "; // This is a closure

  return function() {
    console.log(salute + name);
  }
}

var greet = greeting("Dave");

greet();    // Hello Dave
```

You can learn a lot more about closures in the Kyle Simpson's book series [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) but for this particular topic check [You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures). He uses a simple and up to the point language to explain difficult concepts like this one.

Comment: How does repeating code similar to but not quite the same as in the question answer the question? The OP's code also returns a function that accesses a variable (an argument) of the outer function.

Comment: Is not the same and that proves that you don't understand how Closures or JavaScript works, but if you read the links I shared you will.

Comment: I said "similar to but not quite the same". You have provided a generic closures example that is not significantly different to the `sum()` function in the question, and you haven't answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @DaveGomez Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I was really looking for the specifics down to each step, to have a complete imagine of the lexical environments created, and of the variable scopes. Your links look good reading though, thanks again

Answer (score -1):

here is what happening

1) If a function returns a function and that returned function gets called immediately that's called `currying` (A functional programming term). You have mixed `currying` and `closure` both concept in this example.

2) First your `sum(1)` part gets called . which will return `function(b) {return a+b}` (lets refer it as #1st) , but with It will keep alive `a` as 1 for the for the context of #1st only.

3) As the functions argument is a function call itself then that argument part will get called . e.g `sum(1)(sum(2))` , here `sum(2)` part will get called and it returns `function(b) {return a+b}` (lets refer it as #2nd), also It will keep alive `a` as 2 for the context of #2nd only (closure).

4) Now we are immediately invoking #1st with #2nd as parameter with that currying syntax - #1st(#2nd)

5) so our `a` is unallocated variable and have value `1`, `b` variable has a value `function(b) {return a+b}` . As we are concatenating these two, so final output is `1function(b) {return a+b}`

N.B. - a) In case you wanted a sum of a+b and not that weird output just change your final line as `console.log(sum(1)(2))` . b) In case you noticed closure `a` having value of 2 in the function referred as #2nd is never getting used anywhere but alive .

Comment: Your definition of "currying" is incorrect: whether the returned function is called immediately has nothing to do with currying, nor are all functions that return a function examples of currying. Also, why would there be a memory leak when no references to the returned functions are kept?

Comment: 1) Ya changed to` potential leak if saved` 2)  I amn't defining currying , I was explaining currying in simple terms.

Comment: @sapy Thank you for taking the time. But I'm not really following your explanation. What do you mean when you say, "a is closure"? Isn't closure a function and its lexical environment? One more thing. You say sum(2) gets called first, but using this website: http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=function+sum(a%29+%7B%0A%0A%0A++return+function(b%29+%7B++%0A++++return+a%2Bb%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(+sum(1%29(sum(2%29%29%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0

Comment: @sapy it shows that, a gets defined as 1 first. That's what why I got confused. Because if the closure happens first, it makes sense to me, that a  will always equal 1 no matter what. Otherwise, if it happens later, shouldn't a be replaced by 2? Thanks again

Comment: @SeanCobb , Closure not necessarily always a function` What is closure in javaScript.` 
1) a closure is the local variables for a function — kept alive after the function has returned, or
2) a closure is a stack-frame which is not deallocated when the function returns (as if a ‘stack-frame’ were malloc’ed instead of being on the stack!).

Comment: You are misusing the term "memory leak".